# Asus AC1200 USB AC53 Nano Wifi adapter does not work on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, usb, asus, adapter

I got a new USB Wi-Fi adapter (ASUS AC1200 USB-AC53 Nano) and have failed to make it work in Ubuntu 18.04. I've tried now a lot of possible solutions such as [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2395729) and also installation from [this](https://github.com/Mephysto666/rtl8822bu) repo but the OS still fail to recognize the Wi-Fi adapter. I can see it when lsusb though. The solutions tried so far compiled and installed correctly. After that I reboot the PC and it stays in the closing Ubuntu screen and I have to turn it off manually. After turning it on again nothing happens. It is just that the Wi-Fi adapter is not recognized. I'd appreciate your help

EDIT:

At this point I made a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04. The following is the output of lsusb. There's no 8822bu module because after the fresh installation I haven't tried any of the drivers yet. Which one you recommend me to try first?

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0328 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0b05:184c ASUSTek Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Kernel version:

```
5.3.0-46-generic
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands:  `lsusb` and also: `sudo modprobe 8822bu && dmesg | grep 8822`

Comment: @chili555 I've just edited the question with the output for lsusb

Comment: What is your kernel version? `uname -r`

Comment: @chili555 Kernel version
5.3.0-46-generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend this git repository: https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu/tree/5.6.1.6_35492.20191025_COEX20180928-6a6a

It compiles with a few possibly harmless warnings on my 5.3.xx system.

The procedure is outlined clearly at the github page but if you get stuck, please post back and I'll help.

Comment: I'm gonna try it right away and will let you know

Comment: It worked perfect! Thank you very much for that. I had tried so many drivers, even the one in that repo but at that point maybe there were conflicting versions or something. Anyway, this one worked without effort

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found this link: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=255594
hope it will help!